# How to open nodes in Lightbox?

Tags: 6, nodes, javascript

Goal here is to just open my Nodes in a Lightbox.
Following is what I have tried at it is not working for me, any clue would be great:

In my View, I am rewriting the node title as following:

```
<a href="/node/[nid]/lightbox2" rel="lightframe" title="Full Node View">[title]</a>
```

All I see that the title is output as a link to the node. Clicking on the title just opens the new node.

I followed the instructions at https://drupal.org/node/252260

> Basic example:
>   Search google

I am using Drupal 6! (D6 Version: 6.22 & lightbox2 Version: 6.x-1.11)

Update: I tested this works in my D7 installation - but not in my D6 site. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution - had a silly error.
In lightbox2 module configuration page, under Page Specific Lightbox2 Settings, I was telling it to not load on any page.